# How to connect to Elasticsearch in OJet project?

Tags: elasticsearch, oracle-jet

I have created an index using Elasticsearch. Now I want to communicate to elasticsearch from Ojet project and get the data from the index in JSON format.

How can I achieve this? I did not find any examples about this topic, could you please help with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Elastic search in general but when using Oracle JET the ideal way to communicate with with a backend server is via a **REST API**.

Elastic search seems to offer an **REST API**, please checkout there documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html

You can use the Oracle JET *common model* + *collection API* ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/jet/4.2.0/develop/using-oracle-jet-common-model-and-collection-framework.html#GUID-4A3558F1-7EAB-41F2-BEAA-0F40B35A12C3)) or use jQuery to do AJAX calls and handle the logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.